# Bathroom Sink Odor

Tags: smell

I have recently replaced my bathroom vanity with a new vanity top and built in sink. When I turn on the water, especially the cold, there is a smell like rotten eggs that is coming from the vent in the sink. How can I get rid of this problem. This only occurs in this sink.

Comment: "Vent" in the sink?  Drain?  Overflow drain?  Faucet?

Answer (score 1):

Use Clorox on the sink drain as follows:

Run some hot water from the faucet. Pour 1/2 cup of concentrated Chlorox down the drain. Rinse the concentrated chlorox out of the cup with 2 or 3 *small* potions of hot or warm water, putting each in turn into the drain. Let sit for 1 h or more. Report results to us.